# Another "Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE users(
  id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Now, I want to add another table

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id bigint unsigned,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES mydb.users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I am unable to create the above table due to

```
Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I can't see anything wrong. What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you adding a database prefix? These should be two tables in the same database. Check that they're both InnoDB as well, not MyISAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for which database engine you are using. You should use InnoDB and not MyISAM.

MyISAM does not have foreign key support.